# How to read complex excel like class routine using Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I am actually dont understand how to read excel like class routine using Asp.Net and store the data to MongoDB. Please help me to solve the problem.

My Routine Model class is like below

```
public class Routine
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string DayName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TimeSlotClass> Classes { get; set; }
}
public class TimeSlotClass
{
    public string TimeSlot { get; set; }
    public string RoomNo { get; set; }
    public string CourseCode { get; set; }
    public Boolean isNoClass { get; set; }
    public string TeachersInitial { get; set; }
}
```

And My routine excel sample is 
[image: Class Routine Sample excel file]